# How to Upload Inline-Images using Graph API Batch Request?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload images using Graph API Batch Request, but i'm unable to upload using inline image, can anyone help me please?

Batch Request Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Photo batch uploads: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

Photo batch uploads blog post code works fine, but i want to upload images from my server and not from my pc, Ex: /public_html/image/pic.jpg and i'm not sure how i can do it.

**EDIT:** I'm using PHP SDK 3.0.1

Here's my code:

```
<?php
   CODE WAS CHANGED AND THE PROBLEM IS FIXED ALREADY, SEE THE ANSWER BELOW
?>
```

This is from their docs:

> Uploading binary data
>
> Binary data can be specified as part of the multipart/mime portion of
>   the batch API request. The batch Graph API allows uploading multiple
>   binary items as part of a batch call. In order to do this, you need to
>   add all the binary items as multipart/mime attachments to your
>   request, and need each operation to reference its binary items using
>   the "attached_files" property in the operation. The "attached_files"
>   property can take a comma separated list of attachment names in its
>   value.
>
> The following example shows how to upload 2 photos in a single batch
>   call:

```
curl 
     –F  ‘access_token=…’ \
     -F  ‘batch=[{“method”:”POST”, \
                  “relative_url”:”me/photos”, \
                  “body”:”message=My cat photo” \
                  "attached_files":"file1" \
                 },
                 {“method”:”POST”, \
                  “relative_url”:”me/photos”, \
                  “body”:”message=My dog photo” \
                  "attached_files":"file2" \
                 },
                ]’
     -F  ‘file1=@cat.gif’ \
     -F 'file2=@dog.jpg' \
    https://graph.facebook.com
```

**EDIT 2:**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first issue I see is that the Batch should not be part of the URL, but rather part of the params ...

See the crude batch example below:

```
$batch = array();

$req = array(
    'method'       => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => '/me'
);

$batch[] = json_encode($req);

$req = array(
    'method'       => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => '/me/albums'
);

$batch[] = json_encode($req);

$params = array(
    'batch' => '[' . implode(',',$batch) . ']'
);
try {
    $info = $facebook->api('/','POST',$params);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $info = null;
}
if(!empty($info)){
    if($info[0]['code'] == '200'){
        $user_profile = json_decode($info[0]['body']);
    }
    if($info[1]['code'] == '200'){
        $user_albums  = json_decode($info[1]['body']);
    }
    echo "<pre>User Profile:\n";
    print_r($user_profile);
    echo "\nAlbums\n";
    print_r($user_albums);
    echo "<pre>";
}
```

Notice specifically how the $facebook->api call is formatted ...

EDIT:

Here is a working batch picture upload:

```
$files = array(
    '/data/Pictures/pic1.jpg',
    '/data/Pictures/pic2.jpg',
    '/data/Pictures/pic3.jpg'
);

//Must set upload support to true
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$batch     = array();
$params    = array();
$count = 1;
foreach($files as $file){
    $req = array(
        'method'         => 'POST',
        'relative_url'   => '/me/photos',
        'attached_files' => 'file' . $count
    );
    //add this request to the batch ...
    $batch[] = json_encode($req);

    //set the filepath for the file to be uploaded
    $params['file'.$count] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $count++;
}
$params['batch'] = '[' . implode(',',$batch) . ']';

try{
    $upload = $facebook->api('/','post',$params);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $upload = null;
}

//View the results ...
if(!is_null($upload)){
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($upload,1) . "<pre>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Just tested and it works like a charm ...

Comment: @dleiftah Hello sir, i have been trying your solution and i don't seem to get it to work. it is giving me (#324) Requires upload file.

Comment: I needed to upload to a page's photo album, '{$album_id}/photos' not '/me/photos' - worked for me when I added $params['access_token'] = $page_access_token; Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not too sure and I cannot check at the moment, but

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Look it up at CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, it says:

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. **To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path.** The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in array form to work.

Here is another CURL example:

[CURL PHP send image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image)

So what you need to do is

```
$queries = array(
    array("method" => "POST", "relative_url" => "me/photos","body" => "message=cool","attached_files" => 'file1')
);
```

and

```
$batch = $facebook->api("/?batch=".json_encode($queries)."&file1=@pic.jpg", 'POST');
```

Comment: Nope, its not working :( tried few other things as well, but no luck:S

Answer (score 0):

```
// // File you want to upload/post
$post_data['file1'] = "@D:/home/2.jpg";
$post_data['file2'] = "@D:/home/1.jpg";

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
// Set URL on which you want to post the Form and/or data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
// Data+Files to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
// Pass TRUE or 1 if you want to wait for and catch the response against the request made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// For Debug mode; shows up any error encountered during the operation
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
 // echo curl_errno($ch);
 // echo curl_error($ch);
// Just for debug: to see response
echo $response;
```

This will work for sure its working for me