# Sent base64 image to URL using curl (php)

Tags: php

I'm to sent an image to the server of one social network using curl. The following code works well if I put the link to the image in $post_params variable. I try to do the same with base64 encoded image and insert base64 code into $post_params variable, but then the code doesn't work. How can I fix the issue and upload base64 image?

```html
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["upload_url"])) {
     
        $upload_url = $_POST["upload_url"];
     
        $post_params['photo'] = '@' . 'image.jpg'; // link
     
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
     
        echo $result;
     
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need to encode it to base64? You can simply send the image. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image).

Comment: @Andrew the point is that I can get this image only as base64 or HTMLImageElement js object after generating it from canvas

Answer (score 0):

> I try to do the same with base64 encoded image and insert base64 code into $post_params variable, but then the code doesn't work.

How doesn't it work? Have you tried using something like [runscope](http://runscope.com) or [requestb.in](http://requestb.in) to see what the request you're sending looks like? Does the service you're sending it to give you a descriptive error?

> How can I fix the issue and upload base64 image?

The file you're sending (`image.jpg`) is it a normal `jpg` file? Or is it a `base64` version of the file? If the services specifies `base64`, are they expecting it as a `multipart/form-data` encoded `POST` with a file that's `base64` encoded? That doesn't make much sense (to me at least).

My guess is they want the image *as* a `base64` encoded string. For that just take your file contents and run it through `base64_encode()`, then pass that as a string parameter.