# Sending an Image to an API using Curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, forms, http-post

I have been very frustrated in my attempt to send an image to an API using Curl. The image is coming from an **html form** from the clients end. When the form is submitted, I check to make sure the file is an image and the image is moved to an uploads folder as such:

```
$location = "ImageUploads/";
if(isset($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"]))
 {
$checkImage = getimagesize($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"]);
if($checkImage !== false){
    $Image = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
    $ImageContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($Image));
    $ImagePosted =true;

    $ImageRealName = $_FILES['Image']['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($Image, $location.$ImageRealName))
    {
        echo 'File Uploaded';
    }
}
else{
echo 'Image not submitted';
}
```

After I move the image to an uploads folder, I initiate the curl Post as such:

```
$baseURL ="https://apithatIamusing.com/api/";
$curl =  curl_init($baseURL);
$myImage = new CURLFile($location.$_FILES['Image']['name'],$_FILES['Image']['type'],$_FILES['Image']['name']);
```

After this, I create a curl_post_data array to include the rest of the api data requirements:

```
$curl_post_data = array(
                            'public_key' => $publicKey,
                            'private_key' => $privateKey,
                            'order_type' => 'Image',
                            'origin_id' => '11111111',
                            'name' => $FirstName,
                            'surname' => $LastName,
                            'photo' => $myImage);
```

I then set all of the Curtopts that I will be using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
```

I then execute and attempt to decode the json response:

```
$imageResult= curl_exec($curl);
                        if($imageResult ===false)
                        {
                            $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                                        curl_close($curl);
                                        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
                        }
                        $imageJson = json_decode($imageResult, true);

                        curl_close($curl);

                        $imageSuccess = $imageJson["success"];
                        $imageMessage = $imageJson["message"];
                        $imageSuccess = $imageJson["result"];

                        echo '<p>imageSuccess:'.$imageSuccess.' </p>';
                        echo '<p>imageMessage: '.$imageMessage.' </p>';
                        echo '<p>imageSuccess: '.$imageSuccess.' </p>';
```

I believe that the issue could be with the $myImage that curl is creating, the api documentation asks for the 'photo' to include the following information:

```
filename="t1.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

But, to my understanding, curlfile is including, the name, content-type and the post name.  Any recommendations or other methods to make this api post call using php would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Php and nginx error logs.

Comment: Try adding this: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data')); and read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image

Comment: @Nitin I haven't found anything in the error logs, But $info from curl_get info returns this response: array ( 'url' => 'https://apithatimusing.com/r', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.17826299999999995, 'namelookup_time' => 0.124905, 'connect_time' => 0.148896, 'pretransfer_time' => 0.0, 'size_upload' => 0.0, 'size_download' => 0.0, 'speed_download' => 0.0, 'speed_upload' => 0.0, 'download_content_length' => -1.0,

Comment: 'upload_content_length' => -1.0, 'starttransfer_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => 'xx.xxx.xx.xx', 'certinfo' => array ( ), 'primary_port' => xxx, 'local_ip' => 'xx,xx,xx,xx', 'local_port' => xxxxx, )error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: