# Send a complex data using curl in PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, multipartform-data

I have searched a lot, and found many related questions and forums related to this, but this one is a challenging one.

I'm trying to POST a complex array via `curl`. It has to be `form-data` while the first value in the array is of type `JSON`.
The two other values of array are two images which are uploaded and ready to send.

I tried to run it in `Postman`, and works perfectly fine. I used the generated `PHP` code from `Postman`, but it is not working. Seems like postman is handling some of its tricks without revealing them to us.

Any way, I'm posting a Postman image to illustrate what I mean:
[image]

As you can see, I'm sending the data in `form-data` tab, my first value (`param1`) is a `JSON` with `content-type` `application/json`, the second and third values are images uploaded in `Postman`.

This works just fine in `Postman`.

The problem is, if I set `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` in header, the destination server throws an error saying the `content-type` must be `JSON`.

If I set the `Content-Type:application/json` in header, the destination server says content must be of type Multipart.

Somehow, I need to set both content-types. The main one as `form-data` and the one for param1 as `JSON`.

I paste the Postman code as well, may that be a good start for you fellas to help out with the code.

Postman Code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('param1' => '{
   "AgentId":"1414",
   "ContractId":36529,
   "Files":[
      {
         "FileName":"car_card_front_image.png",
         "FileTypeId":2
      },
      {
         "FileName":"car_card_back_image.png",
         "FileTypeId":2
      }
   ]
}','param2'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/images/icons/car_card_back_image.png'),'param3'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/images/icons/car_card_front_image.png')),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'authenticationToken: xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxx'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

The PHP generated code by postman, ***is not working***. One of the reasons can be that there's no content-type mentioned in it.

I tried modifying the code, adding content-types in header and in parameter, nothing seems to work.

If `Postman` can do it, we should be able it too, right?

Go ahead, make as much changes as you would or suggest anything that comes  to your mind, I will test them all.

Cheeeeers...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image

Comment: Unfortunately no, Disabling safe uploads is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest the [ixudrra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl) library ?

It would make your life easier ....

```
$response = Curl::to('http://example.org')
        ->withData( array( 'Foo' => 'Bar' ) )
        ->withFile( 'image_1', '/path/to/dir/image1.png', 'image/png', 'imageName1.png' )
        ->withFile( 'image_2', '/path/to/dir/image2.png', 'image/png', 'imageName2.png' )
        ->post();
```

Comment: I sure will give it a knock and let you know
thanks in advance