# Need to retrieve the uploaded image from folder and send the image as form data to api

Tags: php, jquery, rest

I have uploaded an image to a local folder using the below code using ajax and php after some cropping and image zooming functionality.

After this function, the cropped image is sanded to a local folder called upload. But the image is processed with base64 encode and decode model. I want to send the cropped/saved image to an api with out base64 data all I want is send the image as form data/file.

The code that used for image upload is image data is sent as form data and is base64 encoded format

```
url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function(){
var base64data = reader.result;
formData.append('image', base64data);
$.ajax({
   url:'<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/upload.php?>',
   method:'POST',
   data:formData
```

and in upload.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['image'])) {
    $data = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);
    $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
     $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
    $image_name = 'upload/' . time() . '.png';
    file_put_contents($image_name, $data);
}
```

i want to take this image from folder and send this data to an api as file/multipart formdata with out encryption/decrypted format

Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using to communicate with the form data - curl?

Comment: INPUT:

Image FILE AS FORM DATA

Comment: Please share more details. What's your exact question about this code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the image on your drive you can use `curl` with `curlFile` option for the purpose. Docs for [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [curlFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

From the docs you can see its usage

```php
/**
 * @param string $file -> full file path
 * @return CURLFile
 */
function makeCurlFile($file)
{
    ## Create the curl file for upload
    $mime = mime_content_type($file);
    $info = pathinfo($file);      # or simply use $name = basename($file);
    $name = $info['basename'];
    $output = new CURLFile($file, $mime, $name);
    return $output;
}

$file = '/path/to/your/upload/directory/picture.png';
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/api_url");
$photo = makeCurlFile($file);

## Construct your post data in an array
$postData = [
    'fileObject' => $photo,                 # fileObject is the name of the file which your api is expecting
    'desc' => 'your custom description'     # Any other field that need to be sent along with the file, use as many needed
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $result = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Note:

1. This applies to php >=  5.5.0. For versions prior to that you cannot use `curlFile` and need to use `@` and build the `body` of the content manually. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433581/4882134) or [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115161) to see how its done.
2. I have not set the `Content-Type` header. `cUrl` appends this header automatically as it deems fit. At least in my case whenever we ask curl to post an `array` it uses the `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data`. If there is an issue you will need to check headers are setup correctly.
3. `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` A comment in the docs ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115161)) suggest we set the `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to true for all versions >= 5.5. However, the docs is silent on the issue except this [page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php). So I am assuming the default for this for versions >= 5.6 is `true` and hence you do not need to explicitly set it when using `curlFile`. For at least `php 7.2` I can confirm it works without setting this to `true`.

> Uploads using the @file syntax are now only supported if the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option is set to false. CURLFile should be used instead.

4. Make use of `curl_error` and `curl_getinfo` to debug